# Running extracted jar source in intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I extracted a jar file and opened the source code in intelliJ. The directories are filled with .class files. The problem is that there is no run button. How can I run the project in intelliJ? I tried going straight to the directory with the class file containing the main method and running it from the command line but I get a main class not found error.

Comment: There is no "project" per se, because you just have a bunch of compiled byte code files.  What was your end goal in unzipping the JAR file?

Comment: That's not source code what you find in JAR files.

Comment: @tevemadar Yes. Your answer answers my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The reason I unzipped the JAR file was to obtain its source code. Reverse engineering in other words. I'm looking at the .class files and I see some source code. I thought I would be able to run that to get back the original software.